# WPF: isolated storage file path too long

Tags: wpf, path, isolatedstorage

I'm deploying my WPF app with ClickOnce. When developing locally in Visual Studio, I store files in the isolated storage by calling `IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForDomain()`. This works just fine and the generated path is

> C:\Users\Frederik\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage\phqduaro.crw\hux3pljr.cnx\StrongName.kkulk3wafjkvclxpwvxmpvslqqwckuh0\Publisher.ui0lr4tpq53mz2v2c0uqx21xze0w22gq\Files\FilerefData\-581750116 (189 chars)

But when I deploy my app with ClickOnce, the generated path becomes too long, resulting in a `DirectoryNotFoundException` when creating the isolated storage directory. The generated path with ClickOnce is:

> C:\Users\Frederik\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\OQ0LNXJT.R5V\8539ABHC.ODN\exqu..tion_e07264ceafd7486e_0001.0000_b8f01b38216164a0\Data\StrongName.wy0cojdd3mpvq45404l3gxdklugoanvi\Publisher.ui0lr4tpq53mz2v2c0uqx21xze0w22gq\Files\FilerefData\-581750116 (247 chars)

When I browse the folders all but the last directory of the path exists. Then when trying to create a folder at this location windows tells me I can't create a directory because the resulting path name will be too long.

How can I shorten the path generated by the IsolatedStorage?

Comment: Do you use a FAT32 partition for your C: drive?

Comment: no, it's an NTFS partition (windows 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i found out it's a limitation of the windows filesystem (around 250 characters limit) and you can't choose or configure the path of the isolated store.

i 'fixed' the problem by changing the isolated storage scope from domain to application... not exactly the best solution but for now it'll do